# Google Cloud Storage bucket - signed URL with directory access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using terraform to create a GCP bucket and signed url, then I'am trying to upload files to this bucket. The process is kind of working but the files uploaded (via curl) are not put inside a desired directory and reather as a directory.

Here is my code:

```
data "google_storage_object_signed_url" "get_url" {
  bucket       = "my_bucket"
  path         = "some_directory/"
  http_method  = "PUT"
  duration     = "24h"
  credentials  = file("keys.json")
}
```

and curl:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file some_file.txt $SIGNED_URL
```

If I use `path         = "some_directory"` ("/" removed) the file uploaded with curl is put as :some_directory" yet its a file, when I use it with "/" the file seem to upload correctly yet it is not visible in that directory.

What am I missing here? Do I have to create s signed_url for every file or can I somehow access the whole directory with it?

Comment: Directories do not exist in Google Cloud Storage. The path separator `/` is just an object name character. Software emulates directories using `prefixes` and `delimiters`. For example the object name `my_files/object_name`, the prefix is `my_files/`. A prefix means, to search for all object names that start with those characters. If you append a `/` to a name, it will be treated as a prefix and basically become invisible with most software. If you use the Cloud Storage JSON API, you will see the object.

Comment: For the title of your question, you cannot create a signed URL for a directory. Since directories do not exist, a URL for one cannot be created. You must create a signed URL for each object.

Comment: More details about folder here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering as a Community Wiki, so that it may help others too.

As @John Hanley suggested in the comment,

Google Cloud Storage does not support directories.  The path separator `/` is just an object name character. Software emulates directories using `prefixes` and `delimiters`. For example the object name `my_files/object_name`, the prefix is `my_files/`. A prefix means to search for all object names that start with those characters. If you append a `/` to a name, it will be treated as a prefix and basically become invisible with most software. If you use the Cloud Storage JSON API, you will see the object.

Accessing the whole directory with a signed URL is not possible because one cannot create a signed URL for a directory. It's worth noting that signed URLs are usually used for single objects (files) rather than directories. So, You must create a signed URL for each object.

Comment: Update: Google Cloud CDN now supports `signed URLs with a URL prefix` [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#programmatically_create_signed_urls_with_a_url_prefix).